# *length* of the longest sequence of consecutive square-free integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It may seem like a duplicate question but I am looking for the *length* of the longest sequence of consecutive square-free integers not to show that there exist.

Comment: It seems likely to me that within a sequence of four consecutive integers one of them is not square-free.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer should be 3, since any 4 consecutive integers contain a multiple of 4, hence not square free.